# How to make the second ul not to show up

Tags: html, css

http://bluemonet.drupal-stg2.rschooltoday.com/

Need some help with the navigation. As on the link above, the "Athletics" tab, the second ul shows up..is there a way that i can hide the second ul and will show up once hover?

Answer (score 2):

In your main.css change your css from this

```
.dropdown:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

to this

```
.dropdown:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

You are showing all UL on :hover, that's why it showing all nested ULs.
To show only first level child you should use > (child) selector.

Thanks